# Restart hiveserver2 on emr

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr

I killed the hiveserver2 process (after finding the PID with `ps aux|grep -i hiveserver2`) on my EMR cluster with one master and two workers. Before killing hiveserver2 I was able to browse and query Hive on my browser via HUE. I tried restarting with `hive --service hiveserver2` but then I can't connect from HUE anymore and it either hangs or says that it can't connect to the `<publicDNS>:10000`

My use case is that I want to modify the hive configuration of my EMR cluster without shutting down the cluster. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
initctl list
status hive-server2

sudo restart hive-server2
sudo stop hive-server2
sudo start hive-server2
```

[How do I restart a service in Amazon EMR?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restart-service-emr/)

Answer (score -2):

Hive configurations can be added before you launch your cluster, not after you have the cluster ready. You can add them as configuration settings in bootstrap step.

E.G. You can add your configurations in hive-site.xml using following syntax (in java):

```
    Map<String,String> hiveProperties = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hiveProperties.put("hive.vectorized.execution.enabled","true");
    hiveProperties.put("hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled","true");
    hiveProperties.put("hive.execution.engine","Tez");
    hiveProperties.put("hive.auto.convert.join","true");
    hiveProperties.put("hive.exec.parallel","true");

    Configuration myHiveConfig = new Configuration()
    .withClassification("hive-site")
    .withProperties(hiveProperties);

    List <Application> apps = new ArrayList<Application>();
    apps.add(new Application().withName("Hadoop"));
    apps.add(new Application().withName("Hive"));
    apps.add(new Application().withName("Spark"));
    //apps.add(new Application().withName("Pig"));
    //apps.add(new Application().withName("Zeppelin-Sandbox"));

    RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
    .withName("abc")
        .withReleaseLabel(emrVersion) //"emr-4.3.0"
    .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
    .withConfigurations(myHiveConfig)
        .withInstances(
                  new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                        .withInstanceCount(numberofInstances)
                        .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)
                        .withTerminationProtected(false)
                        .withMasterInstanceType(mserverType)
                        .withSlaveInstanceType(sserverType) 
                  )
    .withApplications(apps)
    .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
    .withSteps(generalSteps);
```

More details in link below:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html